# ios google maps performselector to show infowindow

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm not sure if this is possible with Google Maps for iOS but I'm trying to refresh the open infoWindow of a marker when modal view controller is dismissed.  Right now, I'm just trying to get the infoWindow to show up manually.  I added a navigationItem button and sending the coordinates to the selector:

```
- (void) dosomething:(id)sender{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(41.05061, 28.77244);
    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc]init];
    marker.position = position;
    [self performSelector:@selector(mapView:markerInfoWindow:) withObject:mapView_ withObject:marker];
}

- (UIView *) mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView markerInfoWindow:(GMSMarker *)marker{
    NSLog(@"%f, %f", marker.position.latitude, marker.position.longitude);
    InfoWindow *infoWindow = [[InfoWindow alloc]init];
    NSDictionary *thisMarker = [NSDictionary new];
    _thisMarker = thisMarker;
    for (NSDictionary *dic in [MainMarkers sharedInstance].mainMarkers){
        if ([[dic valueForKey:@"latitude"]isEqualToString:@(marker.position.latitude).stringValue] && [[dic valueForKey:@"longitude"]isEqualToString:@(marker.position.longitude).stringValue]) {
            _thisMarker = dic;
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", _thisMarker);
    //...infoWindow setUp
    return infoWindow;
}
```

The logs work, I'm sending the specified coordinates but the infoWindow doesn't show up.  Everything works if I tap on the marker.  Is it possible to open the infoWindow this way?

UPDATE:

In the viewWillAppear method, I tried this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewWillAppear:YES];
if (_thisMarker) {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[_thisMarker valueForKey:@"latitude"] floatValue], [[_thisMarker valueForKey:@"longitude"] floatValue]);
    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc]init];
    marker.position = position;
    mapView_.selectedMarker = (GMSMarker*)marker;
    }
}
```

I'll add that I'm using a custom view for the infoWindow.  If I add marker.map=mapView_; the infoWindow comes up but it doesn't get re-drawn, recreated based on the data (marker icon, marker name, marker details)...so I still can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

May want to try this...

```
[self.mapView setSelectedMarker:marker];
```

Comment: Same result as NigelG's suggestion...nothing.  I haven't found a way to call the method to redraw the infoWindow

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a marker on the map, you can just ask the map to select it:

```
self.mapView.selectedMarker = (GMSMarker*)marker;
```

The result is the same as if the user had tapped on the marker.

Comment: I tried your solution and I updated my question...still can't get it to work